# after update trigger sends data to log table and sends tag_id .I need tag Name?

Tags: sql-server

I Have 4 tables:

`Documents`, `document_tag`, `doc_document_tag` and `log`.

- In `document`: `doc_id`, `Doc_name` are saved
- In `Doc_tag`: `Tag_id`,`Tag_name` are saved
- In `doc_document_tag` multiple tags are save against one or more
  documents.

  for every table logs are generated.

My question is that in my case in `doc_document_tag`  only `tag_id` is saved and I need `tag_name`

Answer (score 0):

**Based on your description, the `Doc_Tag` table should have the `Tag_name` you need.**

*In the future, giving actual table definitions, some sample data and the actual expected result will help in getting a more accurate and complete answer.*

**This query example might get you started**

```
  SELECT DT.tag_name
  FROM dbo.logs L
  INNER JOIN dbo.doc_document_tag DDT
  ON DDT.Tag_id = L.Tag_id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Doc_Tag DT
  ON DDT.Tag_Id = DT.tag_id;
```